# Employee autofilling not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Here am written some jquery autofilling code for autocompletion:

```
$("#emp").autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "empauto.do?method=getAutoEmpdetails",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    featureClass:"P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 96,
                    name_startsWith:request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {

                    response( $.map( data.list1, function( item ){

                        return {
                            label: item.empname,
                            value: item.empname,

                            id : item.email
                            +"("
                            +item.phone
                            +"("
                            +item.shift_id
                            +"("
                            +item.deptname
                            +"("
                            +item.emplocation
                            +"("
                            +item.empid
                            +"("
                            +item.employeetype
                            +"("
                            +item.empaddress
                            +"("
                            +item.empdesignation
                            }
                    }));
                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui ) {

            var vals = ui.item.id.split("(");


                 $("#name").val(ui.item.label);
                 $("#email").val(vals[0]);
                    $("#phone").val(vals[1]);           
                    $("#shiftid").val(vals[2]);
                    $("#dept").val(vals[3]);
                    $("#location").val(vals[4]);
                    $("#empid1").val(vals[5]);
                    $("#emptype").val(vals[6]);
                    $("#address").val(vals[7]);
                    $("#designation").val(vals[8]);




    /*log( ui.item ?
        "Selected: " + ui.item.id :
        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);*/
},

open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
},
close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
}
    });
```

Its working fine but after selection am modifying employee information except name and id this update operation also working good.But problem is after modifying employee am doing autocompletion again ,like when give start character r the corresponding employee names displayed in dropdown searchbox.

```
Here problem is previouly modified employees are not coming in searchbox.
```

But my queries is working fine i already checked manually.

So please provide the answer what are the changes required in jauery like js file

Comment: You should update autocomplete source, something like that: `$("#emp").autocomplete( "option", "source",newSourceCall);` Please check the DOC

Comment: @Rugal yes java jquery

Comment: @A.Wolff its not working ,please give me another solution

Comment: @user2996174 "java jquery", what does mean??? And i don't have any other solution because this is the solution you should use. BTW, i don't know code you have tried or if you have any error in console...

Comment: it is not `Java`, it is `JavaScript` with `Jquery` framework...

Comment: Here am  not using select box,only input search box

Comment: @Rugal ,yes javascript with jquery